# win10 IOT on raspberry pi3 or raspberry pi2

Tags: raspberry-pi, windows-10-iot-core

I have a raspberry pi3 but I am having tremendous issues with trying to install win10 IOT on it. When I download the core and try to boot it I only get the "rainbow" screen. When installing noobs I dont even get the option for win10 IOT. Anyone else had problems with this? Will it work smoother on a raspberry pi2 rather then the pi3?

Im not asking if anyone know solutions for booting win10 IOT on pi3, I have tried most of it :) Just asking if anyone has better experiences using pi2 for it?

Comment: Are you currently running Windows 10 or Linux on your Pi?

Comment: Currently nothing. I can get rasbian up and running without any problems what so ever. But when I try to install win10 iot I cant get past the 'rainbow' screen.

Answer (score 0):

If you follow the link to [*Manually set up your IoT Core device*](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/iot/win10/GetStartedManually.htm) Microsoft there explain how to install *with a Windows computer*.

If you are using UNIX however, there isn't much help for you. As an experienced Unix user who last used Windows seriously about six years ago I found it quite intimidating to have to

a) log into my Microsoft account (that I last used from a different continent)

b) sign up as a "Windows Insider"

Even after going through these hurdles I only stumbled across [the ISO file](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10ISO) by accident, and even then nothing for the Raspberry Pi.

This answer isn't given to help you achieve your aim, which I despair of doing, but to let you know that the whole process perplexed someone of considerable experience. I don't see myself using Win 10 for my Pis without buying a pre-configured SD card.

Answer (score 0):

What you're going to need to do is follow this link and do what it says:
https://buildazure.com/2017/05/24/setup-raspberry-pi-with-windows-10-iot-core/

Basically:

1. Load up your microsd card onto the PC
2. Use the wizard
3. Insert card into the Pi
4. And boot it up.

Answer (score 0):

i working in windows 10 iot core.

first time when i install windows 10 iot core i follow the following list.
[how to install windows 10 iot core](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JPRUbGIyODY&t=167s)

follow the link.

i things your problem is solve...

Comment: Links to external resources are encouraged, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline.